# How to prevent shiny plot from being redrawn multiple times per UI interaction?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In my shiny app I have a date range input and a group of checkboxes. The checkbox choices are determined based on the input$dateRange. I'm running into an issue where the plot is being redrawn twice every time the date range is changed. The first time it is redrawn it will use the new date ranges, but the old checkbox choices. Then the checkbox choices are updated and the plot is redrawn a second time.

Is there any way to prevent redrawing the plot multiple times and only have it drawn once all the other UI elements have updated?

server.R code snippet

```
  # Check boxes for variants in run
  output$choose_variants <- renderUI({
    # Get the variants associated with the run
    dat <- loadVariants(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2])
    if(is.null(dat))
      return()

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("variants", "Variants",
                        choices  = dat$variant,
                        selected = dat$variant)
  })

  # Output the data
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    runLocations <- loadRunsBetweenDates(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2], input$variants)
    #ggplot()
  })
```

ui.R code snippet

```
  sidebarPanel(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
      label = 'Date range',
      start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date()
    ),
    uiOutput("choose_variants")
  ),
```

Comment: Florian was faster than me :( `isolate()` is the way to go though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `input$variants` always changes whenever the date range slider changes, you can make your plot dependent on `input$variants` only.

```
  # Output the data
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    # outside of isolate statement, so this plot becomes dependent on its value.
    input$variants

    # put this in an isolate block, so it doesn´t trigger an invalidation.
    isolate(runLocations <- loadRunsBetweenDates(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2], input$variants))
    #ggplot()
  })
```

Hope this helps!

> EDIT: Alternative, based on condition in comment

You could create a reactive, and make your plot only dependent on that as follows:

```
  loadedVariants <- reactive({
  loadVariants(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2])
  })

 # Output the data
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    # outside of isolate statement, so this plot becomes dependent on its value.
    loadedVariants()

    # put this in an isolate block, so it doesn´t trigger an invalidation.
    isolate(runLocations <- loadRunsBetweenDates(input$dateRange[1], input$dateRange[2], input$variants))
    #ggplot()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards `isolate()`. The only problem is that `input$variants` may not always change when the date range changes. It's possible that `loadVariants` will return the exact same values as with the previously selected date ranges. In this case I would still want the plot to be redrawn.

Comment: I added an alternative solution, I have not been able to test it though. Let me know if this suits your desired behavior better.